# BDR Replication

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

I tried setting up the Multi master BDR for postgres, by following the steps provided in the quickstart. I Managed to get the installation and configuration correct(hopefully).

I have two centos 7 servers: X and Y. Where postgres, bdr both were installed.

After adding the entry in pg_hba.conf, postgresql.conf. Restarted the postgres instances on both the server.

```
my pg_hba.conf have on both X and Y: 
host    replication     postgres        X/32          trust
host    replication     postgres        Y/32          trust
```

Also, postgresql.conf is added with changes provided in the quickstart.

I was able to create bdr extension and btree_gist.

On X machine:

```
select bdr.bdr_group_create(local_node_name :='node1', node_external_dsn :='port=5432 dbname=testDB host=IPADDRESS_of_X', node_local_dsn := NULL, apply_delay := NULL, replication_sets :=array['status']);
```

on Y machine:

```
select bdr.bdr_group_join(local_node_name := 'node2', node_external_dsn := 'port=5432 dbname=testDB host=IPADDRESS_of_Y', join_using_dsn := 'port=5432 dbname=testDB host=IPADDRESS_of_X', node_local_dsn := NULL, apply_delay := NULL, replication_sets :=ARRAY['status']);
```

For Testing I ran,

`select bdr.bdr_node_join_wait_for_ready();`  This returned null as expected.

`select '*' from pf_relication_slots;` this gave a slot name with my testDB.

However, when I ran a manual update or insert on the database, I see that the data is not replicating on other node.

```
SELECT * FROM bdr.bdr_nodes
```

Does gives the output as:

[image: Screenshot]

Could someone please help me on this.

Comment: Check the logs. Looks to me like one node hasn't joined yet.

Comment: Yes indeed the node was not joined. And it was available in the log with error: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host. Added entry in pg_hba.conf to resolve the issue. Thanks for the pointer :)

Comment: odd, I thought the join function checked for that...